# Git commands to push and override code

Tags: git

How do I push code I have using git without it complaining to me about conflicts or anything. I want it to ignore conflicts and simply replace what is on our git server with the code I am pushing. How can I do this?

Comment: Hmm... so you want to override the work of your colleagues without reviewing it? The common use-case is pulling the latest changes, merge them and then commit&push.

Comment: Yes, I know the common use-case and yes, I want to override. I have been given the OK to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `-f`.

Note that this will blow away other people's code.